# How to count letters in string using reduce method

Tags: javascript, methods, reduce

I'm trying to make a function that counts duplicate letter values and I would like to do that specifically with the reduce function.

```
    letterFrequency('aaAabb dddDD hhcc')
    Should return: [['d',5], ['a',4], ['b',2], ['c',2], ['h',2]]
```

I want to specifically do this without the use of any loops. Thanks!

This is the problem I'm trying to do:
http://www.codewars.com/kata/53e895e28f9e66a56900011a/train/javascript

But I want to do it with the reduce function.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Do you have any problems using the `reduce` function? Which ones?

Answer (score 4):

I would separate some of the concerns. Rather than trying to write a reduce function that does all of the above, I would break it into 3 parts.

#### The Reduce Function

This function is designed to be passed to a `.reduce` call. It counts the frequencies of the items passed to it.

```
function duplicates(frequency, letter) {
  frequency[letter] = frequency[letter] + 1 || 1;
  return frequency;
}
```

#### A Transform Function

This function transforms a regular Javascript object into the format you specified.

```
function transform(hash) {
  var keys = Object.keys(hash);
  return keys.map(function(key) {
    return [key, hash[key]];
  });
}
```

#### A Wrapper Function

This function wraps around both of the others to create the output you want.

```
function findFrequencies(string) {
  var freqs = string
    .toLowerCase()
    .split('')
    .reduce(duplicates, {});

  return transform(freqs);
}
```

---

#### Sorting Function

Finally, if you wanted to sort the frequencies, then you could write a sorting function which would work with this type.

```
var frequencies = [['d',5], ['a',4], ['b',2], ['c',2], ['h',2]];
frequencies.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[1] - b[1];
});
```

Comment: missing `]` in the transform function.

Comment: The transform function should use map and not forEach. forEach doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Store the result in an object first and then convert that to an array. e.g.

```
function letterFrequency(str) {
  var map = str.replace(/\s+/g, '').split("").reduce(function(result, c) {
    var count = result[c] || 0;
    result[c] = count + 1;
    return result;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(map).map(function(k) { return [k, map[k]]});
}
```

Comment: That's wonderful, how would you sort the count from greatest to least? And to omit the ' ' characters?

Comment: You can remove spaces with replace. I edited my code to include that.

Answer (score 0):

darn! you guys beat me to it.

Basically I push all values into a map and transform that map into a list afterwards

```
var someString = 'aaAabb dddDD hhcc';
var map = {};

// piece of characters I don't need in the result
var unallowedChars = [" "];

someString.split('').reduce(function(previous, current, index, context) {
    // is the current value allowed?
    // let's do something!
    if (unallowedChars.indexOf(current) < 0) {
        if (!map.hasOwnProperty(current)) {
            map[current] = 0;
        }
        map[current]++;   
    }
});
```

And then later on:

```
/**
 * @param {}
 * @return []
 */
var transformMap = function(map) {
    var transformedMap = []
    for (key in map) {
        transformedMap.push([key, map[key]]);
    }

    return transformedMap;
}

console.log(transformMap(map));
```

I ask for forgiveness incase of typo